# Speeding up ReplaceRepeated while truncating to desired order

Tags: replacement, series-expansion, algorithm, performance-tuning

I need to program in an algorithm that recursively makes algebraic replacements which leads to an utterly complicated algebraic function of $x$, but whose final result is only needed at fixed order in the Laurent series in $x$.  I wish to use this fact to make the algorithm go faster.  Here is sample problem that mimics the realistic problem:

\begin{align}f_n(x) &= \sum_{j=1}^4\frac{1}{6+j x}n\left(\frac{1}{x}+j \,f_{n-1}(x)\right); \qquad f_0(x) = {\tt f[0]}\\
F(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^6\frac{1}{2+n x}\left(\frac{n}{x}+f(n)\right) 
\end{align}

The algorithm is to repeatedly insert the first equation into the second one until all instances of $f_n(x)$ turn into $f_0={\tt f[0]}$.  All that is needed in the end is the Laurent expansion out to $\mathcal{O}(x^0)$ (just need the $1/x$ and constant terms).  *nota bene: The sums are there only to lengthen the expression to make Mathematica work harder.*

Here is a naive implementation (with the result on my machine):

```
(*Implementation 1*)
f[n_] /; n > 0 -> Sum[1/(6 + j x) n (1/x + j f[n - 1]), {j, 1, 4}];
Sum[1/(2 + n x) (n/x + f[n]), {n, 1, 6}] //. %;
Timing[Series[%, {x, 0, 0}]]
```

[image: Result of implementation 1]

Performing the actual recursion in the second line is lightening fast.  But the final step `Series` function is painfully slow (4.109 seconds), since the $x$ in the denominators forces *Mathematica* to appeal to its analytical routines to expand things like $\frac{1}{1+x}\approx 1 -x$.

Since all that I need is the first two terms of the Laurent series, I went ahead and, by hand, expanded the fractions $\frac{1}{6+jx}\approx(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{j x}{36})$ and $\frac{1}{2+nx}\approx(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n x}{4})$, with the intention of partially freeing *Mathematica* of painful analytics.

```
(*Implementation 2*)
f[n_] /; n > 0 -> Sum[(1/6 - (j x)/36) n (1/x + j f[n - 1]), {j, 1, 4}];
Sum[(1/2 - (n x)/4) (n/x + f[n]), {n, 1, 6}] //. %;
Timing[Series[%, {x, 0, 0}]]
```

[image]

This is 8 times faster; the more I save *Mathematica* from doing analytic manipulations, the faster it goes.  But I need it to go faster, yet.  How can I carry out the alogorithm  to minimize the extent *Mathematica* has to do computationally costly analytic work?

Here's my failed attempt: ask *Mathematica* drop higher order terms at each stage in the recursion by adding an `O[x]` to the end of the line:

```
(*Implementation 3 [FAILURE]*)
f[n_] /; n > 0 -> Sum[(1/6 - (j x)/36) n (1/x + j f[n - 1]), {j, 1, 4}];
Timing[Sum[(1/2 - (n x)/4) (n/x + f[n]), {n, 1, 6}] + O[x] //. %]
```

[image]

Very fast, but the wrong answer.  It gets the wrong answer because it drops terms like `x*f[n]` as it thinks `f[n]` is order `O[x]^0` when in reality there is a `1/x` part.  What can I do to speed this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Truncate early and often.

```
f[0] = f0;
f[n_] /; n > 0 := 
  f[n] = Sum[
    Series[1/(6 + j x) n (1/x + j f[n - 1]), {x, 0, 0}], {j, 1, 4}];

Timing[
 res = Series[
   Sum[Series[1/(2 + n x) (n/x + f[n]), {x, 0, 0}], {n, 1, 6}], {x, 0,
     0}]]

(* Out[140]= {0.012000, SeriesData[x, 0, {
Rational[1016635, 162], Rational[5, 486] (-3351289 + 835701 f0)}, -1, 
  1, 1]} *)
```

Comment: Note to self: the key is not to use `ReplaceRepeated` but to assign `DownValues`